# Why isn't broadcastIntent a static method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I'm very new to Android. I'm trying to basically use Intents to build an event system, firing an Intent from a plain old Java object to another plain old Java object which acts as an event handler.

From this perspective, it's very odd to me that I need a Context in order to broadcast an intent. For me an Intent should just be a message which I send out and magically gets received by any broadcast receivers which I've registered anywhere in my application.

Why is broadcastIntent a method of Context, rather than a "free procedure" (static method)? Can you describe a situation where `context1.broadcastIntent(intent)` and `context2.broadcastIntent(intent)` would have different effects?

Answer (score 1):

> it's very odd to me that I need a Context in order to broadcast an intent.

`sendBroadcast()` on `Context` is for *device*-level broadcasts. Such calls broadcast to every app on the device.

That does not appear to be what you need.

> For me an Intent should just be a message which I send out and magically gets received by any broadcast receivers which I've registered anywhere in my application.

What you are describing is an in-process event bus. [`LocalBroadcastManager` implements one](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager), though it too needs a `Context` (possibly tied to trying to use the main application thread; I forget the reason). There are other event bus implementations out there, such as greenrobot's EventBus, that do not require a `Context`.

> Can you describe a situation where context1.broadcastIntent(intent) and context2.broadcastIntent(intent) would have different effects?

Well, since `Context` is an interface, there is no requirement for two `Context` objects to share a common method implementation. There is no `broadcastIntent()` method on `Context`, though.

In general, though, `Context` is a god object. Part of the reason why lots of things route through `Context` was that a "context" god object was a popular design pattern back in the mid-2000's, when Android was first being developed.